# Run commands from script

Tags: bash, powershell

I have the following commands to create IIS application pool & web site.

```
appcmd add site /name:MySite /id:15 /physicalPath:c:\inetpub\wwwroot\install /bindings:http/*:80:

appcmd add apppool /name:MyPool

appcmd add apppool /name:MyPool /managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0 /managedPipelineMode:Integrated

appcmd set site /site.name:MySite /[path='/'].applicationPool:MyPool
```

How can I make the commands to run from bash script or another type of script?

I want .bat/.ps file that in one click exuecte the commands.

How can I do it?

For now I'm open "cmd" as administrator, nagivate to c:\windows\system32\inetsrv, copy the commands and past to cmd.

Sorry about the beginner script questions.

Thanks!!

Comment: `PowerShell` has a `WebAdministration` module specially made for `IIS`.  Why are you using "`appcmd`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to handle all of this with the powershell WebAdministration module, you can read up on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=win10-ps).  You can set bindings, certs, all of it using this module.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
New-WebAppPool -Name "MyPool"
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\MyPool managedRuntimeVersion v4.0
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\MyPool managedPipelineMode Integrated
New-WebSite -Name "MySite" -Id 15 -Port 80 -PhysicalPath "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\install" -ApplicationPool "MyPool"
New-WebBinding -Name "MySite" -IPAddress "*" -Port 80 -HostHeader "MySite"
```

If you have trouble, update your question with some more detail and I can update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. and I can run it like that? powershell -noexit "& ""c:\script\iis.ps1"""

Comment: P.S can you please help me to create also application pool and to move the created web site to the application pool? Thanks!

Comment: @Yaakov Please refer to the documentation that I linked.  It should help you do what you need to accomplish